# multiple csv files in row using in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am very new to excel/csv operation in python.

I have 1k+ .xlsx file. Each excel file have 2 sheets , sheet1.csv , sheet2.csv (sheet names are identical in all the .xlsx) . From all the excel file , I have to collect sheet1.csv and have to create new excel with all the sheets.

Sheet1.scv from one excel looks like below:

```
Name    Age     Gender  State   City
N1      22         M    Cal     ABC
N2      32         M    NC      Dur
```

sheet1.csv from another excel looks like below:

```
Name    Age     Gender  State   City
N3      26       F      KLM     PQR
N4      23       M      SC      STM
```

I am looking for output like below **including an empty row** between each sheet data:

```
Name    Age     Gender  State   City
N1      22       M      Cal     ABC
N2      32       M      NC      Dur

N3      26       F      KLM     PQR
N4      23       M      SC      STM
```

I tried this but not able to understand how to proceed ahead for the above work:

```
for excel in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "*.xlsx")):
      df=pd.read_excel(excel,sheet_name=0) #sheet1.csv is the first sheet in all excel
      df.to_excel('Final.xlsx')
```

This code only keeps the last csv data of the excel file. Please help to fix it for the above problem statement.

Comment: Can I ask why you want an empty row? This isn't particularly useful in pandas, why don't you just concatenate the csvs and create a new column that identifies which file the data came from?

Comment: I have to put an empty row because - I have one more csv file and i have to combine both in the same fashion column wise.

Comment: Ok , Got it. I will look for the alternative option . However the answers provided below seems to reasonable. I will edit as per my need keeping your suggestion in mind as well.

Comment: Actually, I re-read the question and you're just dumping the output to excel without any processing in pandas, so the empty row perhaps makes sense since it is for the benefit of excel :)

Comment: It will help me to differ with other csv, i have to do other operations keeping that in mind thats why was looking to empty line:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible, but `integer`s columns will be converted to `float`s:

```
dfs = []
for excel in glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "*.xlsx")):
      df=pd.read_excel(excel,sheet_name=0) #sheet1.csv is the first sheet in all excel
      #if really need empty row 
      df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([np.nan] * len(df.columns)))
      dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs)
df.to_excel('Final.xlsx')
```

Comment: I will type cast it for str.

Comment: Do you have any link for pandas for excel or csv operations apart from panda official docs. I want to learn it in depth. I went through some links but those are covering very basics only .

Comment: @RIshu - I am afraid, not sure if it exist - to depth :(

Comment: Not an issue. I will try to read from bits :) Thank you for the help .

Comment: its not working correctly if there are not same no. of columns and column names in different sheets.

Comment: Getting this `RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects` while doing type caste to `str` for empty line by `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([np.nan] * len(df.columns))).astype(str)`

Comment: @RIshu - I think need `df = df.astype(str).append(pd.DataFrame([np.nan] * len(df.columns)))`

Comment: Still the same issue .

Comment: @RIshu - How it working if use `df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([''] * len(df.columns)))` or `df = df.astype(str).append(pd.DataFrame(['' * len(df.columns)))` ?

Comment: Are data confidental? Is possible send me probleamtic files to my email in my profile? Because it seems some data relative problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172512/discussion-between-rishu-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following operation to concat all the excels in the given path.

```
allFiles = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "*.xlsx"))
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
append = list_.append
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_excel(file_,sheet_name=0)
    append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```